# How can I turn off interrupt that switching threads in OS, on short time, for my critical part of code?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, winapi, posix

As is known, if the executing threads is more than the number of processor cores, the threads are switched between themselves at certain time slots(quanta). This is true for Win/*nix. But, what mechanism is implemented for a threads switching, it is a hardware interrupt that are launching at specific time slots, isn't it?

What number this interrupt(IRQ), can I change/set the value of this time(time slot), and how can I turn off this interrupt, **on short time**, for my critical to performance(real-time) part of code (by using WINAPI/Posix)?

Comment: " how can I turn off this interrupt" - I may be wrong but that  sounds like a really bad idea...

Comment: Using only POSIX functionality, you can't. Besides, it's *never* a good idea to turn of interrupts in a user-space program, and rarely in a driver.

Comment: In most sane OSs you can not do that at all, unless you are running in kernel code.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg But if not only by using OS-API?

Comment: If you want to synchronize threads there are better primitives for that (like semaphore, mutexes, condition variables).

Comment: Most operating systems *might* have functionality for it, but it's most likely different even between related systems (like BSD, Linux, OSX etc). Also, you will probably need elevated privileges to do it.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg It's not for thread-safe, this is for high performance executing a little part of code in real-time.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Do you want your thread to hog the CPU? If so give it a higher priority.

Comment: "it is a hardware interrupt that are launching at specific time slots, isn't it?" No, it isn't. It is one of the numerous functions of the clock interrupt.

Comment: If he's talking about real-time, the issue is probably latency.  He has received a request, and must respond in a fixed maximum time.  This means that 1) his system must use a deterministic scheduling policy, 2) his process must have a high enough priority to be sure of preempting anything else, and 3) any pages of memory it uses must be locked into memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't turn off the timer interrupts for the OS; they're
managed within the OS itself, and are necessary for its correct
functionning.  Under most Unix, you can use `sched_setscheduler`
and/or `pthread_setscheduler` to set the scheduling policy to
`SCHED_FIFO`, and `sched_setparam`/`pthread_setschedprio` to set
the priority; you will then be guaranteed to not be interrupted
by anything unless it has an even higher priority.

Under Linux, at least (and also under other Unix I've worked on),
it is also possible to lock pages into real memory, so you can't
get a page fault on them (which would cause you to wait for the
disk access).  The function in Linux is `mlock`.

Note that you'll probably need special privileges to change the
global scheduler or to use `mlock`.

Comment: Thanks! Set `SCHED_FIFO` and a priority of 99, don't call `sched_yield`, use pinned memory and set `/proc/irq/<N>/smp_affinity` for all IO irq to single same CPU-core - can give me 100% of other CPU-cores. But it's give me globally. May be, can I self call to **soft-IRQ**, and do performance-critical part of my code inside of (soft-IRQ)interruption's code?

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: You generally can't.

Longer answer: If you have a critical task, you could try to up the priority of that thread, but it's not going to help indefinitely, because modern (non-realtime) OS's do not allow a thread to "take all the CPU in the machine".

Further, ANY interrupt can cause your task to be scheduled. The timer is the one that does it based on time-quanta, but for example if another task is waiting for a network packet, that task will be placed in the runnable queue when such a packet comes in, so the scheduler will run at that point, and make a decision if it's time to run another thread (which technically could be NEITHER your thread, nor the network-packet-waiting thread). Likewise, if your thread touches some memory that has been swapped out to disk, it obviously can't continue until the data has been read back from disk, so it will be "parked" in the blocked queue and some other thread from the runnable queue. When the block has been read from disk, the OS will reschedule again.

There is really no (easy) way around this. And any way that isn't easy will involve messing with drivers and almost writing your own OS.

Comment: "modern OS's do not allow a thread to take all the CPU in the machine": Unix certainly does, at least with real time options, and I'm willing to bet that all of your real time OSs like VxWorks also do.  It's more or less essential if you want to do any real time processing.

Comment: @JamesKanze: added "non-realtime".

Comment: I wouldn't consider Linux to be a realtime OS (but the functions which allow playing with the scheduler and changing priorities _are_ considered "real-time" extensions by Posix).

Comment: Regular linux, without patches, will not allow a single thread to run indefinitely - at it CERTAINLY won't allow the turning off of interrupts.

Comment: That's not what the man pages say: "A SCHED_FIFO process runs
until either it is blocked by an I/O request, it is preempted by
a higher priority process, or it calls sched_yield(2)."  If you
set `SCHED_FIFO` and a priority of 99 (the highest under Linux),
don't do any IO, and don't call `sched_yield`, you can use 100%
of the CPU, forever.  (Of course, you need to be a privileged
user to do this.)

Comment: As for turning of the interrupts: I would hope that this can't be done outside of the kernel, but in (much) earlier versions of Unix, a process running as root could execute a `CLI` instruction without causing a trap.

Answer (score 1):

If you need deterministic scheduling, you will need a Real-time operating system.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system

Comment: Most modern Unices implement the real time extensions of Posix, which, used correctly, result in deterministic scheduling.  (I know that Solaris does, and the man pages of Linux state that it does as well.)

Comment: Sure, but that's some sort of distinct OS hosted in the OS, as you cannot access the full OS features in those extensions. I don't really know Posix ones, I only used a similar extension for Windows (a commercial one) : [link](http://www.intervalzero.com/products/rtx-rtx64/overview/)

Comment: Of course you can.  They're just additional functions, which are not required by Posix.  Nothing's been taken out.